# How do i make this list into a string in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I am trying, in the following code, to encrypt a message. The problem is that my result comes up in a list format instead of a string. How do I make it into a string?

Comment: As far as I can tell, you are trying to do create a string of alternating characters. You want this: `def stringEncrypter(A): return "".join(A[0:-1:2] + A[1:-1:2])`

Answer (score 2):

`finalArray` is clearly a list:

```
finalArray = []
```

To convert it to a string, use `join`:

```
print ''.join(finalArray)
```

But first, you probably do not want these nested lists. You should use `extend`, not `append`:

```
def stringEncrypter(A):
    length = len(A)
    finalArray = []

    if length%2 == 0:
            firstArray=[]*(length/2)
            secondArray=[]*(length/2)
    else:
            firstArray=[]*((length+1)/2)
            secondArray=[]*((length-1)/2)

    for x in range(0, length-1):
            if x%2 == 0:
                    firstArray.append(A[x:x+1])
                    secondArray.append(A[x+1:x+2])
    finalArray.extend(firstArray)
    finalArray.extend(secondArray)

    print ''.join(finalArray)
```

Comment: But, this won't work when `finalArray` is a list of lists, as it is in the question.

Comment: Yes, I changed `append` to `extend` and forgot to mention it.

Comment: Yes this worked. Extend was what i needed. join didnt work without it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to flatten the nested lists in your result and then turn it into a string. Here's one way to do it:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> result = [['I', 'R', 'A', ' ', 'O'], [' ', 'E', 'D', 'Y', 'U']]
>>> ''.join(itertools.chain(*result))
'IRA O EDYU'
```

Comment: Or you can pass the list to `itertools.chain.from_iterable`